# Ошибка в переставлении строк

Tags: java

> ***Задание:** поменять местами 1 строку с последней, 2 строку с предпоследней и тд.(используя тип данных byte)*
>
> **Ошибка** в строчке mas[mas.length-i-1][j] = mas;
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte[][] to byte

UPD: правил код

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte array[][];
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte N = scan.nextByte();
        array = new byte[N][N];
        input(array);
        print(array);
        swap(array, N);
        print(array);
    }

    public static void input(byte mas[][]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                mas[i][j] = (byte) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void swap(byte mas[][], byte a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length / 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                a = mas[i][j];
                mas[i][j] = mas[mas.length - i - 1][j];
                mas[mas.length - i - 1][j] = a;

            }
        }
    }

    public static void print(byte mas[][]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(mas[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы поставили тег "eclipse". Как вы можете это объяснить? Ваша проблема связана именно с этой IDE?

Comment: извините. хотел просто тег IDE прикрепить, который связан напрямую с моей программой.

Comment: если вам нужен тип данных байт, зачем создаете массив типа инт?

Comment: исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо присвоить не `mas`, а временную переменную `a`.

Comment: благодарю, исправил

Comment: @invzbl3 и что, не помогло?

Comment: @StiG все нормально, исправил и получилось)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его решением.